# CarrierWave With Cloudfront Generating wrong URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, asset-pipeline, carrierwave, amazon-cloudfront

Hello I am using Cloudfront with CarrierWave and S3. For some reason in my app I am getting very strange URLs for my cloudfront path when using image_tag and I don't know where I am going wrong. Here is my carrierwave config file

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'                        # required

config.fog_credentials = {
provider:              'AWS',                        # required
aws_access_key_id:     'accesskey',                        #   required
aws_secret_access_key: 'secretaccess key',                          # required
region:                'us-east-1',                  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
}

config.fog_directory  = 'bwautosales'                          # required
# config.asset_host = 'randomletters.cloudfront.net'
config.asset_host = 'randomletters.cloudfront.net'
config.fog_public = true
config.fog_attributes = { 'Cache-Control' => "max-age=#{365.day.to_i}" } #  optional, defaults to {}
 end
```

and my **production.rb** file I have

```
 config.action_controller.asset_host = 'randomletters.cloudfront.net'
```

but in my **view** when I do something like

```
 <%= link_to image_tag(car.images[0], class: "img-responsive right-block", id: index), car %>
```

I get this -

```
src = https://randomletters.cloudfront.net/images/randomletters.cloudfront.net/uploads/car/images/28/car.png"
```

I'm sure this is an easy fix but don't know where I'm going wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

**Image Uploader** `

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

storage :fog

def store_dir
"uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end

def extension_whitelist
 %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
end

end
```

`

Comment: Maybe you should use this instead: car.images[0].file.url

Comment: Thanks for the advice, unfortunately that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: If I remove the line from production .rb it becomes /images/randomletters.cloudfront.net/uploads/car/images/28/car.png"

Comment: can we see the uploader file that you use ? In my case i didn't put config.asset_host = 'randomletters.cloudfront.net' in the main file carrier wave.rb but inside the uploader.

Comment: updated my post above with the uploader

Comment: Try giving, `config.asset_host = 'http://randomletters.cloudfront.net'` in both carrierwave and production.rb, I think you can also remove that line from production.rb

Comment: I have a theory:
Because you set config.action_controller.asset_host = 'randomletters.cloudfront.net' in production.rb then helper such as image_tag will use the CDN url. if you use image_tag it will always prepend https://randomletters.cloudfront.net/images in front of your url thus making the url wrong.
Can you use this in your view instead ?
%img{src: car.images[0].file.url} here you won't rely on the helper from rails but just on the one from carrier wave :)

Comment: Changed to view code to do <img src= <%=car.images[0].file.url%> class = "img-responsive right-block"> </img> which returns the proper url but doesn't load the image even though when I navigate to the url it displays the image?

Comment: are you getting any console errors?

Comment: Just getting a bunch of 403 errors because of the invalid url that my image_tag is creating.

Comment: @Sravan, you think I should remove the line from production.rb (or development for testing), and only keep the .asset host in carrierwave's initializer?

Comment: When I do that it's almost right but it adds /images before the url. Like /images/randomletters.cloudfront.net/uploads/car/images/28/car.png

Comment: have you changed, `config.asset_host = 'http://randomletters.cloudfront.net'` in carrierwave.rb?

Comment: I just removed that line from production.rb. In carrierwave.rb I have `config.asset_host = 'http://randomletters.cloudfront.net'`

Comment: IT WORKED! Thank you so much @Sravan. Seemed like the http:// was the missing key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Carrierwave initializer change the line,
**`config.asset_host = 'randomletters.cloudfront.net'` to `config.asset_host = 'http://randomletters.cloudfront.net'`** to get the required cloudfront URL you needed.

You can also remove the line,  `config.action_controller.asset_host = 'randomletters.cloudfront.net'` from Production.rb as the carrierwave itself fetches from the cloud-front url.

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'                        

    config.fog_credentials = {
    --------------
    --------------
    }

    config.fog_directory  = 'bwautosales'                          
    config.asset_host = 'http://randomletters.cloudfront.net' # please check the change in this line.
    config.fog_public = true
    config.fog_attributes = { 'Cache-Control' => "max-age=#{365.day.to_i}" } #  optional, defaults to {}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of adding credibility to Sravan's answer, I had the same problem and when I followed his instructions it started working properly. If you leave out the **http://** from

```
config.asset_host = <>
```

It gets confused and tries to use a different path with your site's domain name. I had the same issue, but adding **http://** to the beginning of the url fixed it.